# Unexpected behaviour using the ternary operator (Verilog)

Tags: verilog

In the following Verilog module, I'd like to understand why the blocking assignment using concatenation doesn't give the same result as the 2 commented out blocking assignments.

When I run the program on the FPGA, it gives the expected result with the 2 blocking assignments (the leds blink), but not with the blocking assignment using concatenation (the leds stay off).

Bonus points for answers pointing to the Verilog specification explaining what is at play here!

```
/* Every second, the set of leds that are lit will change */
module blinky(
input clk,
output [3:0] led
);
    reg [3:0] count = 0;
    reg [27:0] i = 0;
    localparam [27:0] nTicksPerSecond = 100000000;

    assign led = {count[3],count[2],count[1],count[0]};

    always @ (posedge(clk)) begin
        // This works:
        //count = i==nTicksPerSecond ? (count + 1) : count;
        //i     = i==nTicksPerSecond ? 0 : i+1;

        // But this doesn't:
        {count,i} = i==nTicksPerSecond ? 
          {count+1, 28'b0  } :
          {count  , i+1};
    end
endmodule
```

PS: I use Vivado 2018.2

Comment: 1/ You should use non-blocking assignments. 2/ `i+1` will be 32 bits wide and upset your `{count  , i+1}` bit order.

Comment: @Oldfart I think the use of blocking or non blocking assignment doesn't change anything here since there is a single assignment. Right?

Comment: Always use non blocking assignments in a clocked section. (Yes, even if it is a single assignment!)

Comment: @Oldfart can you explain why or point me to some relevant explanation?

Comment: Because that is the behavior which matches the actual hardware. Search for blocking/non-blocking. There are dozens of posts about the subject.

Comment: @Oldfart from what I read, sometimes it's justified to have blocking assignments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184216/discussion-between-olivier-sohn-and-oldfart).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because the widths of `count+1` and `i+1` are both 32 bits. An unsized number is 32 bits wide (1800-2017 LRM section 5.7.1) and the width of the addition operator is the size of the largest operand (LRM section 11.6.1). To make your code work, add a proper size to your numeric literals

```
 {count,i} = i==nTicksPerSecond ? 
          {count+4'd1, 28'b0  } :
          {count  , i+28'd1};
```

A simpler way to write this code is

```
  always @ (posedge clk) 
      if (i== nTicksPerSecond)
         begin 
           count <= count + 1;
           i <= 0;
         end
      else
         begin
           i <= i + 1;
         end
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is a way for the compiler to generate a warning in that case (like "the stuff on the right is bigger than the stuff on the left")? And how would you simplify this code?

Comment: Unfortunately most tools will not generate a warning as Verilog is weakly typed.

Comment: that's really unfortunate... I guess VHDL would handle this case well (I heard it's strongly typed)

Comment: The question you posted is a perfect example of how easy to make mistake with a concatenation

Comment: A code linting tool should pick up this kind of problem